# write controls in openlayer in jsx format

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers in my react project and for map controls I make a new component to use it. default controls like `full-screen control` are implemented by me like this:

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FullScreen } from 'ol/control';
import MapContext from '../MapProvider';

function FullScreenControl() {
  // /////////////////////////////////////////
  // Contexts
  // /////////////////////////////////////////
  const map = useContext(MapContext);

  // /////////////////////////////////////////
  // Effects
  // //////////////////////////////////////////

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;
    const fullScreenControl = new FullScreen({ tipLabel: 'تمام صفحه' });
    map.addControl(fullScreenControl);

    return () => {
      map.removeControl(fullScreenControl);
    };
  }, [map]);

  return null;
}
export default FullScreenControl;
```

I want to create custom controls in my code for example `map legend` control. after some searching I find that I should use `new Controll` from

```
import { Control } from 'ol/control';
```

but the problem is the `element` in the control constructor only accepts HTML but I want to pass jsx to it.

```
 new Control({
      element:<h1>hi</h1>
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Easy:
  I suggest you try rlayers - https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers which supports this feature and hides all the complexity of doing maps in React (I am the author)
- Harder:
  I am not sure you understand what the `element` argument is - it is not HTML code to be rendered - but rather an existing DOM element. If you want to do this in React, you have to use references - create the DOM element by rendering a component and assign it a reference:

```
const ref = React.createRef(null);
functionn SomeElement() {
  return <h1 ref={ref}>hi</h1>;
}
```

then pass it your control:

```
new Control({element: ref.current})
```

However this behavior is generally considered to be against React guidelines. `SomeElement` will be a dangerous component that won't be reusable. Maps in React are difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've made a React Component like this:

```
const YourReactComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="your-classname">
      Your Component Text
    </div>   
);};
```

Now, you wanted to add this to the map (perhaps like an overlay, but at a fixed position). For that you'd need to create a div to house this component:

```
const yourDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

Now, you'll use ReactDOM.render to encapsulate YourReactComponent into yourDiv.

```
ReactDOM.render(<YourReactComponent></YourReactComponent>, yourDiv);
```

Then, you create the control using the imported module (import Control from 'ol/control/Control.js')

```
const yourControl = new Control({
      element: yourDiv,
    });
```

Then, you finally add it this control to the map

```
map.addControl(yourControl);
```